# ASP.Net Validator line

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax

[image]Im using a regular expression validator to validate an email address that is entered into a textbox. When I click on the textbox a line appears at the bottom of the textbox. How can I stop this line from appearing?

Comment: Its just a line that appears in the bottom of the textbox. I attached a picture but it doesnt seem to be showing up. =\

Comment: Perhaps the line comes from some CSS/styling applied to the textbox?

Comment: I have also noticed that pressing delete or backspace does not work in this textbox either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by a masked edit validator. Once I removed, and used a regex validator instead, all works well.

Answer (score 0):

Try This, use `Display="Dynamic"` in validator.

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" 
        Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="You must enter an email address" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
        Text="*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" />
```

Comment: No, this didnt work. Ive used display="dynamic" to solve the side by side validator issue in the past, but the line is till appearing inside the textbox when I click inside of it.